# Electron child process on cloud foundry

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron, cloud-foundry

I have an app that is running inside of cloudfoundry and needs to kick off a child process using Electron.  This works fine running locally but once I deploy to cloud foundry it fails because the Ubuntu server doesn't have display driver.  I can't use apt-get in the buildpack because cloud foundry restricts the use of any use of `sudo`.  Has anyone run into an issue like this and found a way to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that come to mind:

1. You can manually compile and bundle any required libraries or binaries with your application.  The easiest way to compile compatible binaries is to use the `cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs2` docker image, compile the binaries in that container then extract them out.  You can then `cf push` them with your application.

   This process is very tedious and it's easy to miss required shared libraries.  It also makes your app larger, and you still can't install things that require root access.  I wouldn't recommend it except for small things to augment your app.
2. You can push a docker container, `cf push -o <docker-image>`.  Your Docker image can include whatever binaries you require.  The downside is that not all CF providers support pushing docker images.  I can't guarantee this will work, but it's probably your best shot.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since cloudfoundry allows the use of multiple buildpacks, you can try using the `apt-buildpack`: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack which allows to install  packages within your cloudfoundry machines.

In your `manifest.yml`, specify the apt-buildpack and the node-buildpack (or whatever you use. The apt must come first though!):

```
---
applications:
- name: ...
  memory: 1024M
  instances: 2
  disk_quota: 2048M
  buildpacks:
  - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack.git
  - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack.git
```

Create an `apt.yml` in the root directory:

```
---
packages:
  - <name_of_your_electron_package>
```